# Issue about dict computation

Tags: python, dictionary, finance, computation

I need to calculate the profit&Loss by using two dictionaries, but I dont know where I did wrong and how to perform computation with python dicts.
I need to use the formula `(market price - strike price) * volume`.

Here is my code:

```
    portfolio = {
"AAPL": {
    "volume": 10,
    "strike": 154.12
    },
"GOOG": {
    "volume": 2,
    "strike": 812.56
    },
"TSLA": {
    "volume": 12,
    "strike": 342.12
    },
"FB": {
    "volume": 18,
    "strike": 209.0
    }
}
market = {
"AAPL": 198.84,
"GOOG": 1217.93,
"TSLA": 267.66,
"FB": 179.06
}

def pl(market, portfolio):
global pl
for key, value in portfolio.items():
    pl += (market(value) - (portfolio(value)['strike'])) * (portfolio(value)['volume'])
```

And the error is:

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

[the screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCoi7.png)

Comment: `portfolio` is your dictionary and you can’t call that using `portfolio(value)`. Try `value["strike"]` and `value["volume"]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if is this what you are looking for

```
for key in portfolio.keys():
    pl += (market[key] - portfolio[key]["strike"]) * portfolio[key]["volume"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing your `dict`s incorrectly.

Did you mean:

```py
for key, value in portfolio.items():
    pl += (market[key] - (value['strike'])) * (value['volume'])
```